# Inserting a new entry into a 1 dimensional numpy array without distrubing other entries

Tags: python, arrays

Consider the following: If I have a 1 dimensional array like the following

```
import numpy as np
x=np.array([1,2,4,5])
```

Say now that I have the number 3, and wish to enter it into the 3rd position of the array (or 2nd position in "python language") without distrubing other entries so that we once we call array again after the function, we obtain:

```
x=np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
```

I'm looking for some kind of, for a lack of a better word, "splicing method" involving the array x and the number 3.

Thank you!

Comment: [numpy.insert()](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.insert.html) can do that

Answer (score 0):

You can use ***numpy.insert***

```
numpy.insert(arr, obj, values, axis=None)
```

**arr** -> array you want your value/values inserted to

**obj** -> could be an integer, a slice or a sequence of values

**values** -> as you can imagine, the value/values you want to insert

**axis** -> it works also for multi-dimensional array

Here's the solved example that you have proposed:

```
import numpy as np

idx = 2
val = 3

x = np.array([1,2,4,5])
x = np.insert(x,idx,val,axis=0)
```

Here's the **result**

```
pre-insert : [1 2 4 5]
post-insert : [1 2 3 4 5]
```

As you can see, this method will put in the **position *idx=2*** of the **array x** in the **value *val=3***